# how to prevent navigate backwards, and only rotate and move forwards for navigation?

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using navigation stack and using teb_local_planner for path planning. But when I use it, I found there's problem for the robot because it will move backwards while my laser can only detect the forward area. Is there any parameter that I can adjust to make it only rotate and move forward?

I've searched on the website, someone said they change the min_vel to negative, and someone said to change the escape_vel to 0. I have no idea about these, and maybe other parameters I need to know in advance?

Anyone familiar with teb_local_planner? I'm glad to hear your advice. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272462/how-to-prevent-navigate-backwards,-and-only-rotate-and-move-forwards-for-navigation?/) by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you have a differential drive robot.

Unfortunately, we cannot restrict the optimzer's search space to positive velocities only, since our solver does not support hard-constraints. But you can penalize backwards motions by significantly increasing parameter `weight_kinematics_forward_drive`.
Increase the value by using rqt_reconfigure until you find a satisfactory value (too large values might reduce convergence speed).

Furthermore, you can reduce `max_vel_x_backwards` to 0 (or it is better to reduce this paramter to at least the value of parameter `penalty_epsilon` from a numerical point of view; the value is 0.1 by default; I am going to improve this behavior in future versions).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on 2017-10-07**:
Never thought about this solution.
Sounds pretty reasonable, I'll do as what you have said by changing these parameters . Hope I will get a good result.

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-07**:
@vcdanda did you?

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2023-05-29**:
@croesmann If Teb doesn't support hard constraint, so how does it treat with kinematics, which must be strictly adhered to ?